# Segmentation fault when pointing a non-nullptr struct

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, nullptr

I'm basically working on a program that allows you to make simple genograms, using C++ in a Linux environment.
Here's the entire code I've made for now: ***genogram.h***

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>      

using namespace std; 

namespace genogram
{
    typedef string Name;
    typedef char Relationship;
    struct personNode; // to be defined in genogram.cpp
    typedef personNode* Genogram; // a genogram is identified by the pointer to the first person entered

    const Genogram emptyGenogram = nullptr;
    
    Genogram createEmptyGenogram();
    bool addPerson(Name, char, string, string, Genogram&);
    
    Genogram getMother(Name, const Genogram&);
    bool hasMother(Name, const Genogram&);
    Genogram getFather(Name, const Genogram&);
    bool hasFather(Name, const Genogram&);
    Genogram getPartner(Name, const Genogram&);
    bool hasPartner(Name, const Genogram&);
    bool arePartners(Name, Name, const Genogram&);
    bool hasSons(Name, const Genogram&);
    bool isSon(Name, Name, const Genogram&);
    bool areBrothers(Name, Name, const Genogram&);
    
    bool areRelated(Name, Name, const Genogram&);
    
    bool addRelMother(Name, Name, Genogram&);
    bool addRelFather(Name, Name, Genogram&);
    bool addRelCouple(Name, Name, Genogram&);
    bool addRelChildToCouple(Name, Name, Name, Genogram&);
    
    void printGenogram(Genogram);
    
    bool deletePerson(Name, Genogram&);
}
```

***genogram.cpp***

```
#include "genogram.h"

using namespace genogram;


void debugg(int n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
}


struct son
{
    personNode* person;
    son* nextSon;
};

son* emptySon = nullptr;

struct genogram::personNode
{
    Name name;
    char sex;
    string birthDate;
    string deathDate;
    personNode* mother;
    personNode* father;
    personNode* partner;
    son* linkSons;
    personNode* nextPerson;
    bool visited;
};

//**************************************************//

//Returns an empty Genogram
Genogram genogram::createEmptyGenogram()
{
    return emptyGenogram;
}

//**************************************************//

Genogram createPerson(Name n, char sex, string bDate, string dDate)
{
    personNode* p = new personNode;
    p->name = n;
    if(sex=='M'||sex=='F')
        p->sex = sex;
    else
        return emptyGenogram;
    p->birthDate = bDate;
    p->deathDate = dDate;
    p->mother = emptyGenogram;
    p->father = emptyGenogram;
    p->partner = emptyGenogram;
    p->linkSons = emptySon;
    p->visited = false;
    return p;
}

son* createSon(personNode* p)
{
    son* s = new son;
    s->person = p;
    s->nextSon = emptySon;
    return s;
}

personNode* getPerson(Name n, Genogram g)
{
    Genogram aux = g;
    while (aux!=emptyGenogram)
    {
        if(aux->name==n)
            return aux;
        aux=aux->nextPerson;
    }
    return emptyGenogram;
}

bool member(Name n, Genogram g)
{
    return (getPerson(n,g)!=emptyGenogram);
}

bool genogram::addPerson(Name n, char sex, string bDate, string dDate, Genogram& g)
{   
    if(member(n,g))
        return false;
    Genogram aux = createPerson(n,sex,bDate,dDate);
    if(aux==emptyGenogram)
        return false;
    aux->nextPerson = g;
    g = aux;
    return true;
}

//**************************************************//

Genogram genogram::getMother(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(member(n,g))
        return getPerson(n,g)->mother;
    return emptyGenogram;
}

bool genogram::hasMother(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    return getMother(n,g)!=emptyGenogram;
}

Genogram genogram::getFather(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(member(n,g))
        return getPerson(n,g)->father;
    return emptyGenogram;
}

bool genogram::hasFather(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    return getFather(n,g)!=emptyGenogram;
}

Genogram genogram::getPartner(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(member(n,g))
        return getPerson(n,g)->partner;
    return emptyGenogram;
}

bool genogram::hasPartner(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    return getPartner(n,g)!=emptyGenogram;
}

bool genogram::arePartners(Name n1, Name n2, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasPartner(n1,g))
        return (getPartner(n1,g)->name==n2);
    else
        return false;
}

son* getSonList(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(member(n,g))
        return getPerson(n,g)->linkSons;
    return emptySon;
}

bool genogram::hasSons(Name n, const Genogram& g)
{
    return getSonList(n,g)!=emptySon;
}

bool genogram::isSon(Name s, Name p, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasSons(p,g))
    {
        son* sonAux = getSonList(p,g);
        while(sonAux!=emptySon)
        {
            if(sonAux->person->name==s)
                return true;
            sonAux = sonAux->nextSon;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool genogram::areBrothers(Name n1, Name n2, const Genogram& g)
{
    son* sonAux = emptySon;
    if(hasMother(n1,g))
    {
        sonAux = getSonList(getMother(n1,g)->name,g);
        while(sonAux!=emptySon)
        {
            if(sonAux->person->name==n2)
                return true;
            sonAux = sonAux->nextSon;
        }
    }
    if(hasMother(n1,g))
    {
        sonAux = getSonList(getFather(n1,g)->name,g);
        while(sonAux!=emptySon)
        {
            if(sonAux->person->name==n2)
                return true;
            sonAux = sonAux->nextSon;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool genogram::areRelated(Name n1, Name n2, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasMother(n1,g))
    {
        Genogram aux = getMother(n1,g);
        //when here, segment. fault
        if(aux->name==n2)
            return true;
    }
    if(hasMother(n2,g))
        if(getMother(n2,g)->name==n1)
            return true;
    if(hasFather(n1,g))
        if(getFather(n1,g)->name==n2)
            return true;
    if(hasFather(n2,g))
        if(getFather(n2,g)->name==n1)
            return true;
    if(arePartners(n1,n2,g))
        return true;
    if(isSon(n1,n2,g))
        return true;
    if(isSon(n2,n1,g))
        return true;
    if(areBrothers(n1,n2,g))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//**************************************************//

bool genogram::addRelMother(Name s, Name m, Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasMother(s,g)||!member(s,g)||!member(m,g)||s==m)
        return false;
    personNode* aux = getPerson(s,g);
    aux->mother = getPerson(m,g);
    
    personNode* aux2 = getPerson(m,g);
    son* sonAux = createSon(getPerson(s,g));
    sonAux->nextSon = aux2->linkSons;
    aux2->linkSons = sonAux;
    return true;
}

bool genogram::addRelFather(Name s, Name f, Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasFather(s,g)||!member(s,g)||!member(f,g)||s==f)
        return false;
    personNode* aux = getPerson(s,g);
    aux->father = getPerson(f,g);
    
    personNode* aux2 = getPerson(f,g);
    son* sonAux = createSon(getPerson(s,g));
    sonAux->nextSon = aux2->linkSons;
    aux2->linkSons = sonAux;
    return true;
}

bool genogram::addRelCouple(Name n1, Name n2, Genogram& g)
{
    if(arePartners(n1,n2,g))
        return true;
    if(areRelated(n1,n2,g)||hasPartner(n1,g)||hasPartner(n2,g)||!member(n1,g)||!member(n2,g)||n1==n2)
        return false;
    personNode* aux = getPerson(n1,g);
    aux->partner = getPerson(n2,g);
    
    personNode* aux2 = getPerson(n2,g);
    aux2->partner = getPerson(n1,g);
    return true;
}

bool genogram::addRelChildToCouple(Name s, Name m, Name f, Genogram& g)
{
    if(!arePartners(m,f,g))
        return false;
    return (addRelMother(s,m,g) && addRelFather(s,f,g));
}

//**************************************************//

void genogram::printGenogram(Genogram g)
{
    Genogram aux = g;
    son* sonAux = emptySon;
    while (aux!=emptyGenogram)
    {
        cout << "-----------------\n";
        cout << "Name: " << aux->name << "; sex: " << aux->sex << "; born: " << aux->birthDate << "; dead: " << aux->deathDate;
        cout << ";\n - mother: ";
        if(aux->mother!=emptyGenogram)
            cout << aux->mother->name << ";";
        cout << "\n - father: ";
        if(aux->father!=emptyGenogram)
            cout << aux->father->name << ";";
        cout << "\n - partner: ";
        if(aux->partner!=emptyGenogram)
            cout << aux->partner->name << ";";
        cout << "\n - sons: ";
        sonAux = aux->linkSons;
        if(aux->linkSons!=emptySon)
        {
            while(sonAux!=emptySon)
            {   
                cout << sonAux->person->name << "; ";
                sonAux = sonAux->nextSon;
            }
            cout << "\b\b.";
        }
        aux = aux->nextPerson;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "-----------------\n";
}

//**************************************************//


bool genogram::deletePerson(Name n, Genogram& g)
{
    return true;
}
```

And then here's the ***main.cpp*** where I did some tests:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "genogram.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    genogram::Genogram g = genogram::createEmptyGenogram();
    genogram::addPerson("Mark",'M',"25/09/2001","29/07/2020",g);
    genogram::addPerson("Elizabeth",'F',"31/02/2003","-",g);
    genogram::addPerson("Karl",'M',"04/03/2020","-",g);
    genogram::addRelCouple("Elizabeth","Mark",g);
    
    genogram::addRelMother("Karl","Elizabeth",g);
    if(genogram::areRelated("Elizabeth","Karl",g))  //  true)//
        cout << "Test1: success" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Test1: no success" << endl;
    
    if(genogram::areRelated("Karl","Mark",g))
        cout << "Test2: success" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Test2: no success" << endl;
}
```

Basically, the problem I'm having is that, ***after*** I use `addRelMother("sonName","motherName",g)` to create the relationship between the son and the mother, when I try to see if `"sonName"` is related in any way to `"anotherName"` using the function `areRelated("sonName","anotherName",g)`, a segmentation fault (core dumped) error occurs. More specifically, when this function is executed, it first checks if `"sonName"` already has a mother assigned to him using the function `hasMother("sonName",g)` (which basically simply checks if the function `getMother("sonName",g)` returns `emptyGenogram`, which is an alias for ***nullptr***, or not). After it has returned ***true*** in the if statement, it tries to point to the mother's name, but even though `getMother("sonName",g)` doesn't return an `emptyGenogram`, if I point to the name field a segmentation fault (core dumped) error happens.

```
bool genogram::areRelated(Name n1, Name n2, const Genogram& g)
{
    if(hasMother(n1,g))
    {
        Genogram aux = getMother(n1,g);
        //when here, segment. fault
        if(aux->name==n2)
            return true;
    }
```

Can somebody help me find the reason of why this happens?

Comment: Overall design aside, `using namespace std;` is a bad idea, **especially** in a header.

Comment: You are not checking if getMother() will return emptyGenogram  which you have defined as nullptr. Ofcource that this will crash. I will also suggest refactoring your code, it create/destroy too many new objects everywhere without need and is hard to track.

Comment: @BajMile I don't think that thing is the problem, simply because before using getMother() I use hasMother(), that simply checks if getMother() returns emptyGenogram or not... In fact, I did some testing and I can tell you that it ***doesn't*** return any emptyGenogram... But even though it's not an emptyGenogram, if I point to the name field of the mother, segmentation fault happens...

Comment: Please start using const references everywhere when possible. For example Name n1, Name n2 -->  const Name& n1...., Also in genome.cpp,  should have the namespace genogram also contain the code like in the header. Your project seems interesting so I wish you luck :)

Comment: @BajMile Thank you so much! It's a project for university stuff, eventually it got interesting to me too, ahah! EDIT: Also thank you for your corrections, very appreciated. :)

Comment: Please, before even posting here, extract a [mcve]. Not only is it required as part of your question, it also helps you to focus on the actual problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing at this line:

```
 sonAux = getSonList(getFather(n1, g)->name, g);
```

You can easy see that getFather() is returning null:

```
 Genogram gg = getFather(n1, g);  // it is null
 sonAux = getSonList(gg->name, g);
```

You need to simplify and refactor your code. Also consider using smart pointers.